# How does iCloud Keychain store unsecured wifi hotspot information?

Tags: macos, ios, keychain, icloud

### Setup

- I connected to an [XFINITY wifi hotspot](http://wifi.comcast.com/) (SSID `xfinitywifi`) roughly 2 hours ago on my iPhone 5S (iOS 7.1.2). These hotspots require no username or password (unencrypted), but do require authenticating with a Comcast username/password at the captive portal web page after connecting. (image below)

[image: xfinitywifi network information]

- I have [iCloud Keychain](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5813) enabled on my iPhone and on my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.9.4). The information for `xfinitywifi` was automatically copied to my MacBook Pro. (image below)

[image: OS X wifi network list]

- I have Safari set **not** to remember usernames and passwords on either device (this is unrelated to wifi and my question below, but I thought it might potentially give clarity to some readers/answerers).

---

### Question

**How (or perhaps where) does iCloud store this unsecured hotspot network information for syncing with other devices which have iCloud Keychain enabled, especially devices running OS X?**

On encrypted networks, the information is stored in the [Keychain Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain_(Apple)#Keychain_Access) app as an "AirPort network password" keychain entry. However, there is no entry for `xfinitywifi` in Keychain Access. I even searched for various other related strings such as `comcast`, etc. but found no relevant entries (see screenshot below).

[image: Search in Keychain Access]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one can see you have the "Remember Networks this computer has joined" Enabled.

When you join new network, that information is saved in the

```
com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
```

located in SystemConfiguration folder.

Obviously iCloud gets that file.

**EDIT**

Since you asked a new question and want to know how iCloud does that read this. (and click on User defaults database to expand)

[Designing for Key-Value Data in iCloud](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesigningForKey-ValueDataIniCloud.html)

> To store discrete values in iCloud for app preferences, app
>   configuration, or app state, use iCloud key-value storage. Key-value
>   storage is similar to the **local user defaults database**; but values
>   that you place in key-value storage are available to every instance of
>   your app on all of a user’s various devices. If one instance of your
>   app changes a value, the other instances see that change and can use
>   it to update their configuration.

[image: iCloud]

and

[image: iCloud2]

Comment: Tell me more about the "Obviously iCloud gets that file" part.

Comment: For example, can you link me to some documentation that lists the manifest of files that are synced with "iCloud Keychain" and their location in the filesystem?

Comment: iCloud may not be getting that specific file, but it's getting some of the data from it, at least.  Apple doesn't publicly document how iCloud or Keychain Sync works, so there is no way to know for sure without reverse engineering it (the sync operation is basically a black box.)  It would probably be necessary to set up an SSL proxy to examine the packets coming into/out of your Mac and also running a root-level process to log all filesystem access to see what it's actually doing (and that still wouldn't tell you how Apple stores it on their end although you might see what is being sent.)

Comment: @pattern86 see my update explaining how iCloud knows your Airport preferences. (saved networks)

Comment: It clearly says it is used to store/transfer system preferences files from to iCloud.  Why would you assume that Apple is not using it?? It is a method described by Apple how to set up iCloud (for developer) and it is the system in use by Apple.

Comment: True, it's likely that they are (replacing my previous comment above with this one.)  Page 27 of the document they released today about iCloud security - https://ssl.apple.com/privacy/docs/iOS_Security_Guide_Sept_2014.pdf shows that it's used for other parts of the keychain sync.  They don't specifically document how the (unencrypted) WiFi networks are synced, though.

Comment: That is because the unencrypted networks do not reside in keychain. There is no need to secure those, it is just another Starbucks WiFi.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Before marking this question as accepted, I want to make sure I understand what you're saying is that (1) the location you listed is **where** it's stored (I can and have verified that), and that (2) you don't *know* **how** it gets stored there, but it's probably via the method you cited from the developer site?

Comment: you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have a keychain in your Keychain Access named 'iCloud' and that is where webforms and application passwords and airport passwords are saved, and synced via iCloud keychain sync.